# Error object has no attribute in Paint app

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the code, I got it from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uW-NLL9dlBs

After many attempts, I solved some issues, but I still couldnt get it to work.

Its supposed to be an app for painting. I wanted it to have very large pixels with invisible grid too, so painting in it would create low resolution pixel art, similar to this. I dont know how to do that, as I couldnt find it anywhere. [pixel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbgWq.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Scale
from tkinter import colorchooser,filedialog,messagebox
import PIL.ImageGrab as ImageGrab

class Paint():
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Paint")
        self.root.geometry("800x520")
        self.root.configure(background='white')
        self.root.resizable(0,0)

    self.pen_color = "black"
    self.eraser_color = "white"

    self.color_frame = LabelFrame(self.root,text='Color',font = ('arial',15),bd=5,relief=RIDGE,bg='white')
    self.color_frame.place(x=0,y=0,width=70,height=185)

    colors = ['#ff0000','#ff4dd2','#ffff33','#000000','#0066ff','#660033','#4dff4d','#b300b3','#00ffff','#808080','#99ffcc','#336600','#ff9966','#ff99ff','#00cc99']
    i=j=0
    for color in colors:
        Button(self.color_frame,bg=color,bd=2,relief=RIDGE,width=3,command=lambda col =color:self.select_color(col)).grid(row=i,column=j)
        i+=1
        if i==6:
            i=0
            j=1

    self.eraser_button = Button(self.root,text="ERASER",bd=4,bg='white',command=self.eraser,width=8,relief=RIDGE)
    self.eraser_button.place(x=0,y=187)

    self.clear_button = Button(self.root, text="Clear",bd=4,bg='white',command=lambda : self.canvas.delete("all"),width=8,relief=RIDGE)
    self.clear_button.place(x=0,y=217)

    self.save_button = Button(self.root,text="Save",bd=4,bg='white',command=self.save_paint,width=8,relief=RIDGE)
    self.save_button.place(x=0,y=247)

    self.canvas_color_button = Button(self.root,text="Canvas", bd=4 , bg='white', command=self.canvas_color(),width=8,relief=RIDGE)
    self.canvas_color_button.place(x=0, y=277)

    self.pen_size_scale_frame = LabelFrame(self.root,text="size",bd=5,bg='white',font=('arial',15,'bold'),relief=RIDGE)
    self.pen_size_scale_frame.place(x=0,y=310,height=200,width=70)

    self.pen_size = Scale(self.pen_size_scale_frame,orient=VERTICAL,from_ = 50, to = 0,length=170)
    self.pen_size.set(1)
    self.pen_size.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=15)

    self.canvas = Canvas(self.root,bg='white',bd=5,relief=GROOVE,height=500,width=700)
    self.canvas.place(x=80,y=0)

    self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>",self.paint)

def paint(self,event):
    x1,y1 = (event.x-2),(event.y-2)
    x2,y2 = (event.x + 2),(event.y + 2)

    self.canvas.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill=self.pen_color,outline=self.pen_color,width=self.pen_size.get())

def select_color(self,col):
    self.pen_color = self.eraser_color

def eraser(self):
    self.pen_color = "white"

def canvas_color(self):
    color = colorchooser.askcolor()
    self.canvas.configure(background=color[1])
    self.eraser_color = color[1]

def save_paint(self):
    try:
        filename = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.jpg')
        x = self.root.winfo_rooty() + self.canvas.winfo_x()
        y = self.root.winfo_rooty() + self.canvas.winfo_y()
        x1 = x + self.canvas.winfo_width()
        y1 = y + self.canvas.winfo_height()
        ImageGrab.grab().crop((x,y,x1,y1)).save(filename)
        messagebox.showinfo('paint says','image is saved as ' + str(filename))

    except:
        messagebox.showerror("paint says","unable to save image ,\n something went wrong")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    p = Paint(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please include all relevant information to your question, such as the full error traceback. Please take the [tour] if you haven't yet already and take a look at [ask] to higher your chances to get an answer to your question.

Comment: The code appears to have indentation issues. it appears that `self.pen_color = "black"` and many of the lines following it need to be indented one more level. I don't know if that's the problem you're asking about since you didn't provide a full error message.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your paint program working, the following bugs need to be addressed.

The `self.canvas_color_button` command has a bug. Just remove the parens to make it work.

There's a problem with color selection methods.
Here is the solution.

```
def select_color(self,col):
    self.pen_color = col


def eraser(self):
    self.pen_color = self.eraser_color
```

When saving a drawing, the image is not cropped correctly due to other widgets.

`self.color_frame` has a width of 70.
Your canvas is defined with a borderwidth(5) and a highlightthickness(2).
These values must be taken into account.

Here is one solution to crop your saved images correctly.

```
xoffset = self.color_frame.winfo_width()
yoffset = int(self.canvas["borderwidth"]) + int(self.canvas["highlightthickness"])

x = self.root.winfo_rooty() + self.canvas.winfo_x()
y = self.root.winfo_rooty() + self.canvas.winfo_y() + yoffset
x1 = x + self.canvas.winfo_width() - xoffset
y1 = y + self.canvas.winfo_height() - (yoffset * 2)
```